# Repeated Requests for apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png with apple-touch-icon set in head

Tags: android, html

I've set paths for my apple-touch-icon files in the head of my page:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
```

but every so often I get a batch (more than five at a time) of requests for /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png from Android users.  Is this normal behavior and how do I get it to stop?  I know I can add the file but I don't want to have to create a new version of the files and hope I get the same effects.

**Update**
We've recently been seeing requests for apple-touch-icon-144x144.png and I haven't found anything online that explains why we would need that (we added it anyways).

Comment: Huh? I haven't got a clue what you are asking.  Do you mean that you are seeing requests from Android browsers (or at least those with an Android agent ID) to download a file from your website?

Comment: @Simon Yes that is what I'm seeing.  It's not acknowledging the apple-touch-icon links in my head.

Comment: Ah, got it.  It's an Apple specific thing.  My guess is that since no browser except Safari will understand that tag, Chrome, or Android stock or whatever browser will simply treat it as an HREF.  I don't know enough HTML to suggest a way to avoid it.

Comment: These requests are similar to FAVICON requests as described here on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Device_support). You can generate a apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png pretty easily [here](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/icon_slayer) from an image you have and drop it in to your root directory if you want to move on quickly. HTH.

Comment: I can feel your frustration. Apple is just totally out of their mind. Even when using the rel links, Apple still tries to look for the "precomposed" first - triggering a 404. the best way to deal with it would be to htaccess-prevent any such requests.

Comment: @mark note that this issue here is about **Android** devices, not iOS. For me, the problem is that some Android devices ignore the `<link>` tags and look for the file in the root. (Maybe they don't ignore the `<link>` tags, and just try the made-up URL in addition.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/android-apple-touch-icon/

'... Android 2.1 ... will only use the icon if you link to it with a rel value of “apple-touch-icon-precomposed”.'

So it seems to be 'normal' (doesn't work with the non-precomposed version).

Also see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14

Size for high-resolution iPad: 144 x 144